# find and delete gives false status

Tags: shell, find, rm, tcsh

I tried to execute delete as per many previous discussions occurred [find & delete](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/152513/can-find-work-more-efficiently-to-delete-a-large-number-of-old-files/152545#152545)

however my attempts lead to different experience.

```
find . -type d -name "koko" -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

deletes the folder named `koko` but give me false alarm

```
find: ./koko: No such file or directory
```

what is supposively going wrong at my terminal.

I am using `tcsh` , and `-delete` switch with find doesn't work well.

here is the snapshot of [image: workout done]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the `-prune` option as suggested in [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/115869/47538) answer, the error message doesn't occur.

Quoting from the above answer,

> Use `-prune` on the directories that you're going to delete anyway to
>   tell find not to bother trying to find files in them.

**Testing**

```
mkdir koko
cd koko
touch file{1,2}
cd ..
find . -type d -name "koko" -prune -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

After I execute the above `find` command, I get the prompt without any error. However, if I do not use the `-prune` option, I get the same error as you mention.

Comment: it worked fine as you suggest. [find definition](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1489277/how-to-use-prune-option-of-find-in-sh) made it more clear

Comment: @JigarGandhi, glad it resolved your issue. :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `find` has found a directory, it matches your selection and then the command is executed. However, `find` wants to do what comes naturally, and that's recursing through a directory tree, but the directory it's just found has disappeared! Hence the error message.

You can work around this by supplying the `--depth` option, which means *process each directory's contents before the directory itself*. The manpage also mentions that the `-delete` option also implies this option, which is for the above reason.